# Mongoose updateOne update two properties with similar names

Tags: mongoose

I'm Updating the value for one property with updateOne(), but is affecting other property with similar name. (Using mongoose 5.9.9)

```
var file = new Schema({
    name:  String,
    file_image:  String,
    file_image_preview:  String,

  });

// I have this document
{
    name:  'file.jpg',
    file_image:  'http://localhost/image371.jpg',
    file_image_preview:  'http://localhost/image371_preview.jpg',
}

// I use the updateOne method
file.updateOne({_id: '5e969e2e43c2433470c19f67'}: ,
 { $set: {
      file_image_preview: 'http://localhost/image371updated_preview.jpg'
 }
})

// The document is updated to this
{
    name:  'file.jpg',
    file_image:  'http://localhost/image371updated_preview.jpg',
    file_image_preview:  'http://localhost/image371updated_preview.jpg',
}
```

It's a problem with the naming convention?

Answer (score 1):

Try using findOneAndUpdate() method

```js
const filter = { _id: '5e969e2e43c2433470c19f67' };
const update = {
  file_image_preview: 'http://localhost/image371updated_preview.jpg'
};

file.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update);
```

[Link for the findOneAndUpdate() Method](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html)